# How to overlay two videos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, video, playback

I got video A, and video B. What I am trying to achieve is, run video B (Opacity 50% or whatever) on top of Video A.

Is that possible?

I am currently using the AxWMPLib library for video playback.

Comment: How about showing us what you have tried ? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: This post would usually apply: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question . In this case, controls like video players commonly don't support things like opacity, so if yours doesn't, then no. Did you try a plain MediaElement (WPF)?

Comment: Marcelo, please don't add "I have problem", "thank you" to the post. Also "tried alot"/"searched alot" text in the post provides zero insight into what you've actually found/tried (I'removed it from post) - add info on what you actually tried and how it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

If a solution is not available at time of rendering, you could consider **merging the two videos at the source, as a work-around**. Your satisfaction with such a blunt approach would likely depend on how often you need to accomplish this. Needing to be able to change the parameters of the overlay in real-time would obviously make this work-around a no-go.